# Number of maximal subgroups in finitely generated amenable groups

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, amenability, maximal-subgroup

The following statement is known to be true:

> Any subgroup of a finitely generated group lies in a maximal subgroup

*Proof:*

Suppose, $G = \langle \{x_1, … , x_n\} \rangle$ is a counterexample. Then there exists an infinite ascending tower of proper subgroups $H_1, H_2, … $ such that $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} H_i = G$. Then $\forall g \in G \exists i(g) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g \in H_{i_g}$. It follows, that $\bigcup_{j < n} H_{i(j)} = G$ which contradicts the assumption that all those subgroups are proper.

*Q.E.D.*

This fact gives the rise to the question:

> Do all finitely generated groups have finitely many maximal subgroups?

The answer is obviously «**NO**» as there are two types of counterexamples coming to the mind: the free groups and the Tarski monster groups.

However, if we additionally require the group in question to be [amenable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group#Case_of_discrete_groups), then both those examples become ruled out. So, my question is:

> Do all finitely generated amenable groups have finitely many maximal subgroups?

Comment: Actually infinite groups with finitely many maximal subgroups are pretty rare. I'm not sure there exists any finitely generated group with this property.

Comment: PS: actually, the first Grigorchuk group has only finitely many maximal subgroups (namely its subgroups of index $2$). This is due to E. Pervova: *Everywhere dense subgroups of a group of tree automorphisms.* (Russian. Russian summary)
Tr. Mat. Inst. Steklova 231 (2000), Din. Sist., Avtom. i Beskon. Gruppy, 356–367; translation in
Proc. Steklov Inst. Math. 2000, no. 4(231), 339–350.

Comment: @YCor There even exist finitely generated such groups with exactly $3$ maximal subgroups. This is problem 17.17 in the Kourovka notebook and such a group is constructed in §7 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.1489.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf{Z}$ has a maximal subgroup $p\mathbf{Z}$ for each prime $p>0$.

Answer (score 2):

There's even a finitely generated solvable group with uncountably many maximal subgroups, see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249071/finitely-generated-soluble-groups-with-uncountably-many-maximal-subgroups).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is also "NO".

$C_\infty$ has infinitely many maximal subgroups (a subgroup of index $p$ for each prime number $p$). However, it is clearly amenable.

Comment: ...but not finitely generated

Comment: @SeanEberhard it seems OP writes $C_\infty$ for a an infinite cyclic group. So it's finitely generated and your answer is a copy of this one.

Comment: Oh right, my mistake!